# lsldap: command not found and is there any other function we can use similar to lsldap

Tags: linux

we have a command in unix where "lsldap -a entity ***"

Is there any way to implement same functionality in linux

Answer (score 1):

The openldap-clients package has ldapsearch which may do what you want. From the man page:

LDAPSEARCH(1)                                General Commands Manual                               LDAPSEARCH(1)

NAME
ldapsearch - LDAP search tool

SYNOPSIS
ldapsearch  [-V[V]]  [-d debuglevel]  [-n]  [-v]  [-c] [-u] [-t[t]] [-T path] [-F prefix] [-A] [-L[L[L]]]
[-S attribute]  [-b searchbase]  [-s {base|one|sub|children}]  [-a {never|always|search|find}]  [-l time‐
limit]  [-z sizelimit]  [-f file]  [-M[M]] [-x] [-D binddn] [-W] [-w passwd] [-y passwdfile] [-H ldapuri]
[-h ldaphost] [-p ldapport] [-P {2|3}] [-e [!]ext[=extparam]] [-E [!]ext[=extparam]]  [-o opt[=optparam]]
[-O security-properties]  [-I]  [-Q]  [-N]  [-U authcid] [-R realm] [-X authzid] [-Y mech] [-Z[Z]] filter
[attrs...]

DESCRIPTION
ldapsearch is a shell-accessible interface to the ldap_search_ext(3) library call.

```
   ldapsearch opens a connection to an LDAP server, binds, and performs a search using specified parameters.
   The filter should conform to the string representation for search filters as defined in RFC 4515.  If not
   provided, the default filter, (objectClass=*), is used.

   If ldapsearch finds one or more entries, the attributes specified by attrs are returned.  If * is listed,
   all  user attributes are returned.  If + is listed, all operational attributes are returned.  If no attrs
   are listed, all user attributes are returned.  If only 1.1 is listed, no attributes will be returned.

   The search results are displayed using an extended version of LDIF.  Option -L controls the format of the
   output.
```